# How can I make a relation beetween serializers in Django Rest?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

A simple E-commerce app has 3 models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    """Order model."""
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()

    @classmethod
    def get_total(self, obj):
        """Get total method.

        Calculate the total price of the order.
        """
        details = OrderDetail.objects.filter(order=obj)
        return sum([i.price * i.cuantity for i in details])


class OrderDetail(models.Model):
    """Order Detail model.

    Primary key will be created automatically and inevitably.
    """

    order = models.ForeignKey('sales.Order', related_name='details', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cuantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey('products.Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    @classmethod
    def get_product_price(cls, obj):
        """Get product price,

        and put it on the order detail price.
        """
        obj.price = obj.product.price
        obj.save()
        return obj.price

class Product(models.Model):
    """Product model."""

    id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    price = models.FloatField()
```

Product objects are already been created in one endpoint, but I need to create a new order with its order details, all in one endpoint. For that I have to use a ModelViewSet and ModelSerializer. I've tried this way:

```
class DetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Order Detail model serializer."""
    product_id = serializers.CharField()
    product = ProductSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = OrderDetail
        fields = ['cuantity', 'price', 'product_id', 'product']
        read_only_fields = ['price']
    
    def get_product(self):
        """Get the product from his id."""
        
        return Product.objects.get(id=self.product_id)


class OrderDetailedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Order model serializer."""
    details = DetailSerializer(many=True)
    price = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Allows to create details in the same order view."""

        details_data = validated_data.pop('details')
        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for detail_data in details_data:
            # Bring the product so we can put it as foreign key in order detail
            product_data = detail_data.pop('product_id')
            product = Product.objects.get(id=product_data)
            
            order_detail = OrderDetail.objects.create(order=order, product=product, **detail_data)
            order_detail.price = OrderDetail.get_product_price(order_detail)
            order_detail.save()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id', 'date_time', 'details', 'price']


    def get_price(self, obj):
        """Get the total price of the entire order."""

        return Order.get_total(obj)
```

So I try posting this json in the endpoint

```
{
    "date_time": "2020-09-09 08:00",
    "details": [
        {
            "cuantity": 3,
            "product_id": "3"
        },
        {
            "cuantity": 2,
            "product_id": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I should recieve something like this:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "date_time": "2020-09-04T08:00:00-05:00",
    "details": [
        {
            "cuantity": 3,
            "price": 3000.0,
            "product_id": "3",
            "product": {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "Zapatillas",
                "price": 3000.0
            }
        },
        {
            "cuantity": 2,
            "price": 1123.0,
            "product_id": "2",
            "product": {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Caramelos",
                "price": 1123.0
            }
        }
    ],
    "price": 11246.0
}
```

But I get this:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "date_time": "2020-09-09T08:00:00-05:00",
    "details": [],
    "price": 0
}
```

I can't create the details. What am I doing wrong?